# Google Tag Manager - trigger not working on user click

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So I am trying to set up a very simple gtag trigger and event to fire whenever a user clicks on a particular CSS element, but I just cannot get it working.

I am using click element - contains - dash_pts

When I check out the preview to investigate, I see the following for the trigger which is not firing. However, this doesn't make sense to me - the trigger filter variable DOES contain "dash_pts"... why is it not firing?

I must be doing something dumb somewhere but I'm at a loss, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Also please let me know if there are other details I can include that might help identify the issue. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the dot too:

```
.dash_pts
```

and use **matches CSS selector** instead of *contains*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still didn't work

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your updated answer, but that also did not fire the trigger.